# Related Objects Reference Django

Tags: python, django

Given the following code:

## Models.py

```
class Advertisement(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=30)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Gallery(models.Model):
    advertisement = models.ForeignKey(Advertisement, related_name='images')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_directory_path, help_text="Your ad image (Recommended size: 1024x768)")
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, default=timezone.now)
```

## Views.py

```
def do_foo(request):
    search_result = Advertisement.objects.all().order_by('-creation_date')

    return render(request, 'content_search.html',
                  {
                      'search_result': search_result
                  })
```

## page.html

```
{% for ad in search_result %}
    {% for ad_image in ad.gallery_set %}
    <img src="{{ ad_image.image.url }}">
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

How do I access the backwards relation between Advertisement and Gallery? I tried ad.gallery_set and ad.images_set but I could not get the images.

I tried to follow what they say here [Django Relation Objects Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/relations/) and in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992230/django-for-loop-counter-break).

Comment: You gave an explicit name to the backward reference, hence it it is called as you specified: `Advertisement.images`. The `_set` is only added when you do not specify an explicit `related_name`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has `related_name="images"`. So `ad.images` it is.

Edit: as shredding notes correctly, you can't use that directly if you want to loop over it, and need to add `.all` to get a queryset object:

```
{% for ad_image in ad.images.all %}
    <img src="{{ ad_image.image.url }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Maybe related name `"galleries"` would be a bit more clear.

Comment: actually it should be `ad.images.all` because images is a related manager: `https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/relations/`