# Django template iteration / loop count based on condition

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to create an iteration like the a `$i==0; $i++;` from PHP in Django, based on a condition.

```
{% for item in event.products %}         
{% if item.category = "Treat" %}
```

Now - I want to be able to tell how many times has this condition been met (category = treat) and how to stop the for loop after 2 items that match that loop.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

django template system does not permit breaks in for loops nor setting counters, even if [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992230/django-for-loop-counter-break) it is shown how to overcome this limitation in some cases or how to [create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/) new template tags that could help you, maybe you can calculate beforehand your requirements and prepare the list to be printed by slicing it in your view.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @DRC that this business logic is best done in your view code and not in the template.

If you still need a template solution:

```
{% regroup event.products by item.category as grouped_products %}

{% for group in grouped_products %}
    {% if group.grouper == "Treat" %}
        {% for item in group.list|slice:":2" %}
            {{ item.imageURL }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Documentation for [slice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) and [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup).

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. That's great, but how would I then go about echoing some of the variables that I was echoing like so in the old code:

{{ item.imageURL }}

Unfortunately this will go in an ESP so there's no changint he view code.

Comment: `slice` still returns a list. You should be able to just iterate over it. I've changed the example.