# How to find first instance in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

## in my view

```
   context ={
        "items":Items.objects.all(),
        "item_pics":Item_pics.objects.all(),
    }
    return render(request, 'menu/items.html', context)
```

## my object "item_pics" looks like that

```
item_pics = [[{'item_id': 1, 'is_front': False, 'url': 'url_to_the_image1'},
             {'item_id': 1, 'is_front': False, 'url': 'url_to_the_image2'},
             {'item_id': 1, 'is_front': False, 'url': 'url_to_the_image3'},
             {'item_id': 1, 'is_front': False, 'url': 'url_to_the_image4'},
             {'item_id': 1, 'is_front': True, 'url': 'url_to_the_image5'},
             {'item_id': 1, 'is_front': True, 'url': 'url_to_the_image6'},
             {'item_id': 1, 'is_front': True, 'url': 'url_to_the_image7'},
             {'item_id': 1, 'is_front': True, 'url': 'url_to_the_image8'},
             {'item_id': 1, 'is_front': True, 'url': 'url_to_the_image9'}],
             [{'item_id': 2, 'is_front': False, 'url': 'url_to_the_image1'},
             {'item_id': 2, 'is_front': False, 'url': 'url_to_the_image2'},
             {'item_id': 2, 'is_front': False, 'url': 'url_to_the_image3'},
             {'item_id': 2, 'is_front': False, 'url': 'url_to_the_image4'},
             {'item_id': 2, 'is_front': False, 'url': 'url_to_the_image5'},
             {'item_id': 2, 'is_front': False, 'url': 'url_to_the_image6'},
             {'item_id': 2, 'is_front': False, 'url': 'url_to_the_image7'},
             {'item_id': 2, 'is_front': False, 'url': 'url_to_the_image8'},
             {'item_id': 2, 'is_front': False, 'url': 'url_to_the_image9'}]
             ]
```

## my template

```
        {% for pic in item_pics %}
           {% if pic.is_front %}
               <img src="{{ pic.url }}"> 
           {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
```

## The problem

How can pick the first occurrance of `pic.is_front == True` and then stop the for loop

## Another problem

If `pic.is_fron = False` for every picture of the `item_pics` i would like to pick the first pic of the `item_pics`

## in python will be something like

```
for pics in item_pics:
    found = False
    for pic in pics:
        if pic['is_front'] == True and found == False:
            print(pic['item_id'], pic['url'])
            found = True
    if found == False:
        print(pics[0]['item_id'], pics[0]['url'])
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992230/django-for-loop-counter-break

Comment: @marin this will not ssolve the OP problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be better done in python code - either in the view itself or, if not possible, using a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags).

In the view

```
item_pics = [{'item_id': 1, 'is_front': False, 'url': 'url_to_the_image'},
         {'item_id': 1, 'is_front': False, 'url': 'url_to_the_image'},
         {'item_id': 1, 'is_front': False, 'url': 'url_to_the_image'}
         {'item_id': 1, 'is_front': False, 'url': 'url_to_the_image'}
         {'item_id': 1, 'is_front': True, 'url': 'url_to_the_image'}
         {'item_id': 1, 'is_front': True, 'url': 'url_to_the_image'}
         {'item_id': 1, 'is_front': True, 'url': 'url_to_the_image'}
         {'item_id': 1, 'is_front': True, 'url': 'url_to_the_image'}
         {'item_id': 1, 'is_front': True, 'url': 'url_to_the_image'}
         ]
 front_pic = None
 for pic in item_pics:
     if pic["is_front"]:
         front_pic = pic
         break
 else:
     front_pic = item_pics[0]
 context = {"item_pics": item_pics, "front_pic": front_pic}
 return render(....)
```

then in your template you don't have anything else to do than directly use `front_pic`.

using a custom filter (cf the link to the doc for where to put this code):

```
@register.filter
def get_front_pic(item_pics):
     for pic in item_pics:
         if pic["is_front"]:
             return pic
     return item_pics[0]
```

in your template:

```
{% load front_pic from yourtaglib %}

{% with item_pics|get_front_pic as front_pic %}
<img src="{{ front_pic.url }}">
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: @KostadinSlavov as a general rule if there's no simple and obvious way to do it directly in the template then it belongs to python code, and if you cannot do it in the view (because you don't own it) or don't want to do it in the view (because you consider it's really a presentation-only feature and not the view's responsability) then custom tags and filters are your friends.

Comment: OMG... Facepalm `context{"pics":item_pics.objects.all().order_by('is_front')` then in the template pick the first one and that's all

Comment: That's another solution indeed <g> but since you defined item_pics as a list of dicts no one could give you this answer.

Comment: I am sorry bad explanation my bad.. :( Really thankful for your answer @bruno appreciate the time you spent for writing that amazing answer :) Thank you

Comment: Oh and yes,  you don' need `.all()` here, you can just `item_pics.objects.order_by(...)` (idem for anything that returns a QuerySet - `.filter()`, `exclude()` etc). `.all()` is only useful when you have no other conditions about the QuerySet.

Comment: Noted Thank You!

Comment: @KostadinSlavov don't be sorry, it only took me a couple minutes and can be useful for someone else (which is the whole point of SO).