# Is there a way to output just the first element in this if statement, Django template?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

In my table and in the some record I have lot of link_img, but I want only the first link_img, what can I do ?

I have something like this in my temp

```
{% for link in sousimg %}

 {% if article.article_img.id == link.img_link.id %}

    {{ link.link_img }} 

 {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: All things work correctly, but inside the if statement I want only one "link_img", that's the matter I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of question is already present so I suggest having a look at it. 
[django for loop counter break](https://stackoverflow.com/a/992243/9715289)

You have to do a little bit of hit and trial in this case.